# A continuous function from (0,1) to [0,1]

Tags: real-analysis, functions

So today my professor gave a self-check to us to write a continuous function defined on (0,1) whose range is [0,1]. And I thought of a function which I am not sure if it is considered to be continuous or not.

f(x) is a piece-wise function defined as: 
\begin{cases}
       0, &\quad\text{if x < 1/10}\\
       5/4(x-1/10), &\quad\text{if 1/10 <= x <= 9/10}\\
       1, &\quad\text{if x > 9/10 }\\ 
\end{cases}

Thank you for your help and/or hints in prior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is not continuous (or even defined in all places you need it). You can mend your idea by letting
$$f(x)=\max\{0,\min\{1,\tfrac 54(x-\tfrac1{10})\}\}.$$

---

*Remark:* It is also possible to find a cubic polynomial function $f(x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is good. But your presentation isn't entirely correct. You need to use $\leq$ instead of $<$ in a few strategic places, so that the function is actually defined on all of $(0,1)$. And you need to look at that middle expression (i.e. $x$) to make sure it actually says what you want it to say.

Alternately, if you don't like defining by cases, you could use something like $\sin^2(10x)$.

Comment: With the edit that I just made, my function is continuous right?

Comment: Yes, that ought to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be plotted using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/qehqptlvfa). You can fix this by making sure the middle segment actually connects to the two horizontal lines at the $x=\frac{1}{10}$ and $x=\frac{9}{10}$.